# Facebook API: Problem accessing multiple pages from my App via Pages API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Premise:
After solving the mystery of the permanent token access, I have been able to post on my Readerly.Ink page from my app.

Problem:
My app, however, is supposed to post on multiple pages, depending on the language of the content. Hence, I today created the other pages (Readerly - Italiano, Readerly - English etc) but I cannot see them through the app!

Even if i GET /me/accounts, the original/first Readerly.Ink page is all I see. I also tried: /new-page-id?fields=access_token&access_token=your-user-access-token (as per instructions of the Pages API) - but I get an error! :-(

Question:
How do I add the new pages to the app?
Or do I need to create a different app for each page?

As far as I can tell, I created the new pages exactly as I created the first one (I'm the admin) and I added them all to my business account.

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Or do I need to create a different app for each page?

No, you don't need to do that. An app is still able to manage multiple pages.

It used to be that you just granted an app access to manage *all* pages you have admin access to. But since that is obviously a bit broad and risky, Facebook has since changed things - users can specify which of their pages they actually want an app to have access to.

You get asked for that on the login dialog, when the permission is initially requested - but that list does not auto-update later to include any pages you created after that happened.

Currently, there does not seem to be any more practical procedure to get the new pages included, than removing the granted permission, and then asking for it again - upon which the user will be asked to chose which of their *current* set of pages they want to grant access to again.

For a quick fix, you can use Graph API Explorer - use the "get token" functionality, remove the granted `manage_pages` permission, and then ask for it again.

For a public facing app that has other people manage their own pages, probably such a step should be implemented within the app - remove the permission *via API* when necessary, then send them through the login flow again. (Might need to use the `reauthenticate` parameter at this point.)

Comment: Is that solution valid ? revoking permission and then then again ask for permission for same page !!!

Comment: doesn't any other solution that facebook is providing and we don't know about that solution?