# Facebook automatically deauthorizes connection

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior but this doesn't seem to happen to Twitter or other social networks.

I have a script that allows users to share content from their website to their Facebook pages using the Facebook API.

Let's say **User1** installs the script on **Website1** and authenticates the API connection(FB Login Workflow) using my Facebook app to load their page **Cat Toys**; they can share just fine.

Now if **User1** installs the script on **Website2** and authenticates the API connection(FB Login Workflow) using my Facebook app to load their page **Dog Toys**; then **Website1 becomes deauthorized** and gives the error:

`The 'manage_pages' permission must be granted before impersonating a user's page.` when it tries to share using the API.

If they go back to **Website1** and *redo the connection*, then *Website2 becomes deauthorized* and then begins to give the error.

How can the same user share content from both their **Website1** and **Website2** to their Facebook pages authorized through my app without one of their connections getting deauthorized?

The only solution I can think of at this time is creating another Facebook app but this wouldn't be ideal or scalable

EDIT:

By "the connection" I mean the Facebook Login oauth workflow which lets a user authorize a script to load their Facebook info, in this case the pages they manage, and allow the script to create posts to those pages. I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have to explain what you actually do with the Facebook API. What does "authenticates the connection" mean? What API calls are you making?

Comment: @WizKid I updated it a bit, by "the connection" I mean the Facebook Login oauth workflow which lets a user authorize a script to load their Facebook info, in this case the pages they manage, and allow the script to create posts to those pages

Comment: Users can select which of their pages they want to grant an app access to now. There is a bit of an issue when it comes to selecting pages they became an admin of after they initially granted your app permission, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953001/10955263 - this here is probably something similar.

Comment: @04FS I've seen this bug ticket, unfortunately it's not the same, it's not a matter of adding a new page and not getting access to it. It's not being able to authorize an app so it gets access to your user pages on multiple websites.

As in: 

Authorize "Example App" on Website1 where it loads(gets) the user's pages which the script can then share to.

Then authorize on Website 2, where it again loads the pages and be able to share to, but WITHOUT Website 1 becoming unauthenticated.

That's the issue im having

Comment: What do the app settings regarding app domain, platform and OAuth look like? _Can_ one even use the same app on multiple domains these days? I know that was quite problematic, and Facebook seemed to rather deliberately limit it.

Comment: @04FS The app domain, is the domain where the authentication code lives, the platform is website and the OAuth redirect is to the domain where the authentication code lives.

The issue is users cannot seem to authenticate multiple websites using their same Facebook account *through* our facebook app